# Protractor waits 30 secs after page is loaded (Angular 2)

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, protractor

I'm writing my first E2E tests for an Angular 2/4 application with Protractor. This works fine as the pages are loaded and input fields are filled.

One big problem is, that after each page load the test waits for about 30 seconds after the next action is done.

For example, I call the login page of the application with browser.get(). The page is shown in the test browser and after 30 seconds the user and password is filled into the input fields.

Here is my protractor.conf.js:

```
let SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').SpecReporter;

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 60000,
  getPageTimeout: 60000,
  suites: {
    mandators: './e2e/mandators/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  },
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    showTiming: true,
    isVerbose: false,
    includeStackTrace: false,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 120000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
  beforeLaunch: function() {
    require('ts-node').register({ project: 'e2e' });
  },
  onPrepare: function() {
    browser.manage().window().maximize();
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter());
  }
};
```

What could be the reason for this long waiting? Is this a normal behavior?

Comment: are you correctly notifying the next step invocations (done) inside your protractor tests?

Comment: Which version of Protractor are you using? Are you sure there are no open Angular calls in the background (like an interval or something) that will prevent Protractor to see if Angular is ready. In most cases this is the problem

Comment: @quirimmo What do you mean by "notifying the next step invocations" ? I did not see anything like this in any tutorial.

Comment: @wswebcreation I'm using protractor 5.1.1. And there is nothing like an interval. But in the network connections of the developer tools in Chrome I see a websocket connection which is pending. This might be the reason. But the question is: Who is opening a websocket connection?

Comment: Your app, Protractor does not influence that

Comment: The websocket connection seems to be opened by the webpack dev server for the live reload. When I start my application with "ng serve -lr false" (for disabling live reload) then there is no websocket connection. But this has no effect on my tests. Still waiting 30 secs after the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. In my case the problem was that in the source code, I used setTimeout () for 30 seconds. And Protractor all time waited for the end of the timer, and only then he began to run test scenarios.
Solved this problem with the **zone.runOutsideAngular()**